# How to upload multipart file from request body in swashbuckle?

Tags: api, .net-core, swashbuckle

How should I setup swashbuckle in .net core so that I could upload file from request body (multipart, form value model binding disabled)?

What I tried (added FileUploadHelper in swashbuckle startup config, obviously):

```
public class FileUploadHelper : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (operation.OperationId.ToLower() == "apifileuploadpost")
        {
            operation.Parameters.Clear();
            operation.Parameters.Add(new NonBodyParameter()
            {
                Name = "File",
                In = "formData",
                Description = "uploaded file",
                Type = "file",
                Required = true,
            });
            operation.Consumes.Add("multipart/form-data");
        }
    }
}


 [HttpPost, DisableRequestSizeLimit]
 [DisableFormValueModelBinding]      
    public async Task<IActionResult> Upload()
    {
        int id = await Request.StreamFile(fileService);
        return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetFileInfo), id);
    }
```

StreamFile is an extension method that saves file content from request body in filecontent entity (byte[]) and also creates a fileinfo entity with file content id and some additional info (name, description etc.) but returns only generated id. I just want to be able to click upload button in swagger, choose file and get the returned id or error response. I do NOT use IFileForm, form value model binding is disabled (according to large file upload using streaming in asp.net core documentation) and the file is straight from request body so I don't pass any file-related parameter in Upload controller method, only 'this HttpRequest'. Is that even doable in Swashbuckle?

Comment: Hey Mike - Have you found the solution to this problem yet? I'm also looking for it's solution.

Answer (score 3):

Your `FileUploadHelper` class looks good. I think the problem is that the `OperationId` is different. It should be the name of the method which is `Upload`. I have created a sample based on yours and changed the `FileUploadHelper` to match by the route instead I think it is more clear.

Here are the code snippets for my version that works.

The controller:

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class FileUploadController : ControllerBase
{
   [HttpPost, DisableRequestSizeLimit]
   [DisableFormValueModelBinding]
   [Consumes("multipart/form-data")] // You can specify consumes here and it gets automatically added also to swagger
   public async Task<IActionResult> Upload()
   {
      int id = await Request.StreamFile(fileService);
      return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetFileInfo), new { id = id }, null);
   }

   [HttpGet]
   [Route("{id}")]
   public async Task<IActionResult> GetFileInfo(int id)
   {
      return new JsonResult(new { id = id });
   }
}
```

The FileUploadHelper

```cs
public class FileUploadHelper : IOperationFilter
{
   public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
   {
      if (context.ApiDescription.RelativePath == "api/FileUpload")
      {
         operation.Parameters.Clear();
         operation.Parameters.Add(new NonBodyParameter()
         {
            Name = "File",
            In = "formData",
            Description = "uploaded file",
            Type = "file",
            Required = true,
         });;
      }
   }
}
```

Startup with added Swagger settings:

```cs
public class Startup
{
   public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
   {
      Configuration = configuration;
   }

   public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

   // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
      services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

      services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
      {
         c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "File Upload API", Version = "v1" });
         c.OperationFilter<FileUploadHelper>();
      });
   }

   // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
   {
      if (env.IsDevelopment())
      {
         app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
      }
      else
      {
         // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
         app.UseHsts();
      }

      app.UseHttpsRedirection();
      app.UseMvc();
      app.UseSwagger();
      app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
      {
         c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "File Upload API");
      });
   }
}
```

This is how it looks like in the UI.

[image: Swashbuckle file upload]